# Does the UUID of USB device change?

Tags: c++, windows, usb

I'm trying to identify when a specific USB microphone is plugged into windows. The device is using a generic VID/PID.  Our application is asking the user to identify the device as part of setup. We record the UUID of the device and connect to it later. Occasionally windows seem to report that the device with that UUID isn't present.  Does the UUID reported by mmdeviceenumerator ever change?  We are fairly certain the device isn't changing ports for getting unplugged.  The machine may be getting rebooted though.

This will work fine for days on most machines, but then suddenly it's not found.  Our logs show the device isn't available and it appears the UUID is different.

Here's some simplified code on how I'm reading the ids and names:

```
com_pointer<IMMDeviceCollection> devices;
enumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints(flow, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE | DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED, &devices);

UINT count;
devices->GetCount(&count);
for (UINT i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
  com_pointer<IMMDevice> comDevice;
  devices->Item(i, &comDevice)
           
  AudioDevice audioDevice = createAudioDevice(comDevice);   
  if (audioDevice.isFound()) {
    list.append(audioDevice);
  }      
  
  PROPVARIANT name;
  PropVariantInit(&name);
  properties->GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &name);

  PROPVARIANT hardwareId;
  PropVariantInit(&hardwareId);
  properties->GetValue(PKEY_Device_HardwareIds, &hardwareId);
    
  LPWSTR id;
  device->GetId(&id);
}
```

The PKEY_Device_HardwareIds always return an empty string.  Right now I'm storing and comparing the GUID from GetId to see if they are the same device.  Sometimes that GUID changes.  After some research, I suspect it occasionally gets changed due to a windows patch.

Is there a better id to use to keep track of the same device?

Comment: I'm not sure if the UUID is generated by Windows when you plug the microphone in. It that's the case, perhaps it'll generate a different UUID if you plug it into a different USB port? Just speculation. Which method do you use to obtain the UUID btw (please add a link in the question)? I got lost in the documentation :-)

Comment: All USB devices get a UUID.  I'm not sure when it's generated. It seems to be the same even if plugged in different ports. In the field it seems like it changes sometimes.  I just cant seem find documentation about it.

Comment: Ok, but what is the name of the function you use and/or structure you look at?

Comment: I updated with some sample code